# Keyboard Extension doesn't appear in Keyboard Lists

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios8, ios-app-extension, xcode6

In `XCode 6 Beta 4` , my custom keyboard name doesn't appear in lists of Keyboards.

Previous versions of `XCode` , my custom keyboard working fine.

In `XCode 6 Beta 4` , I thinks it's more worse on simulator.

I have also tried `Simulator > Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard Uncheck` and I added keyboard in iOS Settings. But it doesn't work.

Now it's completely disappearing. I have tried Reset Simulator and it's not work.

How can i do it? Is this bug of XCode Beta4?

[image]

Comment: I am having similar issues. Now that I see your comment I am beginning to think it is a Beta 4 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the custom keyboard crashes on its launch. You can check if there are the crash log in Xcode->Device->CrashLogs